# Crop image as columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Consider below image:

[image]

I am trying to create a "simple" Python method, that can crop images like table columns. So for example, an user can define on the image, how it should be cropped, like:

[image]

Here the user have defined three areas on the image, that should be cropped, thus resulting in 4 columns.

I am trying to use `PIL` to crop it, but as far as I can see, it accepts `(left, upper, right, lower) tuple`:

Consider, my columns are stored in JSON format, like this:

```
#COLUMNS:
{"1": {"position":"20"}, "2": {"position":"50"}, "3": {"position":"70"}}
```

So above `position` refers to the position from left side of the image, on the x-axis.

I am having a hard time solving this - how I can crop based only on above information.

I imagine that I will need the full height of the image as a parameter.

This is what I have so far:

```
def columnsFromImage():
    img = Image.open(img_file)
    image_name = img.filename

    width, height = img.size
    for col in COLUMNS:
        col = COLUMNS.get(str(col))

        area = () #This is where I am stuck

        output_image = img.crop(area)
        output_image.save(image_name)
```

As you can see, I am stuck in defining the area. I can't figure out how to calculate the column positions, and crop based on this.

Comment: The column area's coordinates will be (column[i], 0), (column[i+1]-1, image height). Another issue with your code is it's replacing the original image with each column image (or at least will try to do so).

Comment: @martineau I am a bit unsure about the coordinates. Should this be defined in  `area()?`.

Comment: And ah, good catch about the save. I see the problem with that now!

Comment: They're the (left, upper), (right, lower) coordinates of the crop area. If "i" is the last column, you'll want to use  (column[i], 0), and (image width, image height) since there's no column[i+1] to reference.

Comment: But where does `column[i]` comes from? Should it be for left, upper: `(col, 0)` and then for right, lower: `((int(col) + 1) - 1)`, height)?

Comment: It just an abstraction of the column position of the i-th column. In terms of your data structure it'd be the somewhat awkward `int(COLUMNS["1"]["position"])`, `int(COLUMNS["2"]["position"])`, etc… You might want to consider using a list of dictionaries instead.

Comment: Ah OK. Would you mind just posting this as a short answer? I am trying to `for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):` but I get an index out of range error.

Comment: Sorry it's late here and I'm signing-off. I'm fairly sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your area is:

```
upperleft = current column
top = 0
lowerright = next column (column[i+1])
bottom = height of image
```

Because in the last iteration there will be no next column to look at I catch it and just use the width of the image as the last lower right position.
below I made an example what your code could look like.

```
def columnsFromImage():
    img = Image.open(img_file)
    image_name = img.filename

    width, height = img.size

    col = COLUMNS[str(1)]
    area = (0, 0, round(width*(int(col['position'])/100)), int(height))
    output_image = img.crop(area)
    output_image.save(image_name + str(0) + '.png', 'PNG')

    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
        col = COLUMNS.get(str(col))
        pixelsleftcorner = round(width*(int(col['position'])/100))
        try:
            pixelsrightcorner = round(width * (int(COLUMNS[str(i + 2)]['position']) / 100))
            area = (pixelsleftcorner, 0, pixelsrightcorner, int(height))
        except KeyError:
            area = (pixelsleftcorner, 0, int(width), int(height))
        output_image = img.crop(area)
        output_image.save(image_name+str(i+1)+'.png', 'PNG')

columnsFromImage()
```

Comment: Hm it does indeed make the cropping, but it does not seem to be correct? For example, if I give two coordinates: `'{"1":{"position":"50"}, "2":{"position": "70"}}'`, the first image will be very thin (`20px * 880px`), and the 2nd image is the rest of the width: (`915px * 880px`)

Comment: The `50` and `70` is not in pixel, but is the position on the image (50% and 70% to the right)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well. you got the width from the image so calculating the right size from a percentage should not be too much extra work.

Comment: It gives me an invalid syntax on:
`area = (pixelsleftcorner, 0, pixelsrightcorner, int(height))['position']), int(height))`

Comment: That is because I did not test this and the right corner calculation needs to be moved inside of the try

Comment: It still give me an incorrect syntax:
`area = (pixelsleftcorner, 0, pixelsrightcorner, int(height))['position']), int(height))                                                                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: My bad, somehow the , int(height)) stayed from the last time I changed the answer. fixed it now.

Comment: Still syntax error: `area = (pixelsleftcorner, 0, pixelsrightcorner, int(height))['position'])`

Comment: It works for me.. I repasted the code from my editor, hope that fixes it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193243/discussion-between-oliverbj-and-moopsish).